# Copy an OLEObject, and paste it to a folder (or to the Desktop)

Tags: excel, file, vba, object, paste

I have between 1 and 4 attached OLEObjects (zip files) in an Excel spreadsheet.

I can manually right-click > Copy one of the objects, and then go to the Desktop or an Explorer window, and right-click > Paste it to create the zip file in that folder.

As far as I can make out, I can't automate the Paste stage of this process with VBA.

Also, I can't do this manual process with multiple objects simultaneously, so my original hopes of a workaround (copy them all to clipboard then open an Explorer window) won't work.

My best workaround is to copy each object in turn, ShellAndWait the Explorer window, and instruct the user to paste the file, then close the window when done, and move on to the next object.

```
Sub blunt_extract()

If MsgBox("All attachments will be downloaded to your Documents folder", vbOKCancel Or vbInformation, "") = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
Dim o As OLEObject, ws As Worksheet, rM As Range, ATT As String

On Error Resume Next
MkDir modSpecialFolders.SpecFolder(modSpecialFolders.CSIDL_PERSONAL) & "\CIRF\"
MsgBox "For each attachment, Explorer will launch in the CIRF folder.  Right-click > Paste the zip file, then close the Explorer window to continue", , "Save Attachment"
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsA)
For Each o In ws.OLEObjects
    If Left(o.Name, 11) = "Attachment " Then
        o.Copy
        ShellAndWait "explorer " & modSpecialFolders.SpecFolder(modSpecialFolders.CSIDL_PERSONAL) & "\CIRF\", 0, vbNormalFocus, PromptUser
        MsgBox "Done pasting?  Click OK to continue", , "Save Attachment"
    End If
Next o
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Any suggestions for further reading, or even a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since (unfortunately) the Windows Explorer is not automated, we need to command it indirectly by simulating keyboards keys.

I propose this (tested) solution to move embedded OLE objects in a worksheet into a given folder

```
Sub SaveOleObjectsTofolder(ws As Worksheet, folder As String)
    Shell "explorer " & folder, vbMaximizedFocus
    Dim o As OLEObject
    For Each o In ws.OLEObjects
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' necessary, give it a moment
        o.copy
        SendKeys "^v" ' paste in explorer
    Next
    SendKeys "%fc" ' close the explorer
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP posted this almost two years ago and was last seen on StackOverflow in April. I doubt your question will get answered. It may be helpful to generalize your answer as much as possible so the user who placed the bounty could make the easiest use of it, as well as future students.

Comment: @JDB_Dragon oh.. I did not notice that. Thanks for signalling it. Basically my answer addresses the issue of moving embedded OLE objects into a given folder. I will try to modify it to address this general issue without much focus on the OP's code. Thanks again :)